# Automatical label and hyperref label

Tags: hyperref

In my project, before doing exercises or proving theorems, I always state the lemmas that I need to use, and I label-hyperref them manually like so

```
\begin{lemma}\label{1}${}$

...

\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}\label{2}${}$

...

\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}\label{3}${}$

\\ ...

\end{lemma}
```

And anytime I need to mention a lemma, ex lemma 1, in my project, I use the command
`\hyperref[1]{Lemma \ref*{1}}`

But I usually rearrange the order of statement of lemmas. So, if I forget to change the number in the command `\label{}` of some lemma, it will lead to an incorrect mention of the lemma that I need to use. Is there any way to label the lemma automatically so that when I change the order of the lemmas, the lemmas that I mention anywhere in the project also change their index automatically?

Comment: don't use numbers but meaningful names, like \label{lem:fermats-theorem}.

Comment: it is bad style to use  numbers for labels, or to generate them automatically. the whole point of label is an internal identifier that does not change as the visible printed number changed, so you can change the order without having to change all references

Comment: so basically, I need to fix nothing ?

Comment: if you use  `1` as the internal label for theorem 2, latex will do the right thing, but you will confuse yourself, so it is better style to use `\label{pythagorus}`  and leave the numbering to latex.  `\ref{pythagorus}` will track the correct number

Comment: you mean I use \label{pythagorus} for all lemmas ?

Comment: no `\label{abc}` is like `id=abc` in html just pick a unique internal name for each lemma or section, then to reference it use`\ref{abc}` as you edit the document, the number of the lemma will change but the `\ref` will pick up the correct number, you do not need to know what number it is, or worry if it changes